# Converting Nested JSON to DataFrame in R?

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

I'm currently working on a project where I need to convert a nested JSON structure into a DataFrame using R. I'm facing some issues with the current approach, and I'd appreciate any help or guidance on how to properly handle this conversion.

Json file looks like this :

```
json_data <- '{
  "resourceType": "QuestionnaireResponse",
  "id": "example-questionnaireresponse",
  "questionnaire": "Questionnaire/example",
  "status": "completed",
  "subject": {
    "reference": "Patient/example"
  },
  "authored": "2023-12-19T12:00:00Z",
  "source": {
    "reference": "Patient/example"
  },
  "item": [
    {
      "linkId": "page1",
      "text": "Page 1",
      "item": [
        {
          "linkId": "1.1",
          "text": "Quel est votre nom?",
          "answer": [
            {
              "valueString": "Participant 1"
            },
            {
              "valueString": "Participant 2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "linkId": "1.2",
          "text": "Quel est votre âge?",
          "answer": [
            {
              "valueInteger": 30
            },
            {
              "valueInteger": 25
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "linkId": "1.3",
          "text": "Quel est votre lieu de résidence?",
          "answer": [
            {
              "valueString": "Ville A"
            },
            {
              "valueString": "Ville B"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "linkId": "page2",
      "text": "Page 2",
      "item": [
        {
          "linkId": "2.2",
          "text": "Nombre dannées dexpérience?",
          "answer": [
            {
              "valueInteger": 5
            },
            {
              "valueInteger": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "linkId": "2.3",
          "text": "Êtes-vous heureux?",
          "answer": [
            {
              "valueBoolean": true
            },
            {
              "valueBoolean": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

The json file is the response of two partipants to a questionnaire! I'd like a dataframe where each row contains the responses of a participants while a column contains the responses to a specific question.

my approach :

```
df <- fromJSON(json_data) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  unnest_wider(item) %>%
  unnest_wider(item) %>%
  unnest_wider(answer) %>%
  select(linkId, text, valueString, valueInteger, valueBoolean)
```

which obviosuly doesnt work ..

How can I convert a FHIR json file structure to dataframe? an unnested dataframe at that.

Comment: use `jsonlite::fromJSON(json_data)|>as_tibble()%>%unpack(item)%>%unnest(c(status,subject,source))%>%unnest(item, names_sep = "_")` from here, you can decide whether to unnest the other wider or longer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

jsonlite::fromJSON(json_data) %>%  
  pluck("item", "item") %>% 
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            mutate(across(answer, ~ map(.x, ~ as.character(pull(.x, 1))))) %>% 
            unnest_wider(answer, names_sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  linkId text                              answer_1      answer_2     
  <chr>  <chr>                             <chr>         <chr>        
1 1.1    Quel est votre nom?               Participant 1 Participant 2
2 1.2    Quel est votre bge?               30            25           
3 1.3    Quel est votre lieu de risidence? Ville A       Ville B      
4 2.2    Nombre dannies dexpirience?       5             2            
5 2.3    Jtes-vous heureux?                TRUE          FALSE
```